# SET PATH in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was working on a NodeJs project and i ran into this line:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "set NODE_PATH=./lib&& node lib/server.js",
  },
```

As i understand, set NODE_PATH changes the node path so that require functions can look to a different path. If i try to run set NODE_PATH=./lib in a separate line and then run the script it will not work.

> Does this works only when executed in on line?
>
> How it works eventually?
>
> Where can i find docs about the SET function?

Comment: can you show `in a separate line`, how you tried

Comment: set NODE_PATH=./lib and then node lib/server.js

Comment: scripts are ececuted in shell (assuming you're in linux, similar thing for windows), `set` sets the named env variable for that *instance* of shell. **in a separate line**, am assuming two different script commands? if that is the case those two scripts are executed in 2 different shell so whatever you `set` in one is not available to the other

Comment: Put it in an answer to vote. Also the source?

Comment: `set` comes from `os` so it could be windows or linux or some other *nix. Let me try to compile an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm` scripts are `shell scripts` which are executed on the host machine's shell. `set` command comes from the host `os` (so you should check for cross platform compatibility)

> Does this works only when executed in on line?

Yes. `set` sets the env variable for that instance of shell. It's available to only that instance and it's subshells.

*If i try to run set NODE_PATH=./lib in a separate line*

Am assuming this means two different script commands (because json does not allow multiline). If so, those two scripts are executed in 2 different instance of shell so whatever you `set` in one is not available to the other

> How it works eventually?

Executes shell script

> Where can i find docs about the SET function?

Here's a link to `man` of [`set`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html) for linux. You can google for your `os` if you're not using linux.